# Match pattern in select statement

Tags: regex, postgresql

I want to match `| ^^^ *` exactly

in a PostgreSQL select statement using `regexp_matches` or any other method.

I tried

```
regexp_matches(column2, E'(?i)\| ^^^ *')
```

but no match for `| ^^^ *`

```
select  column1, regexp_matches(column2, E'(?i)\| ^^^ *') from  table ;
 regexp_matches
----------------
 {""}
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just use `LIKE` here:

```
SELECT
    column1,
    CASE WHEN column2 LIKE '%| ^^^ *%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS match
FROM your_table;
```